# What are the new $Metrics tables on Azure storage emulator?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I notice on my Azure Storage Emulator the following tables:

```
$MetricsCapacityBlob
$MetricsTransactionBlob
$MetricsTransactionsQueue
$MetricsTransactionsTable
```

On my Production environment:

```
WADDiagnosticInfrastructureTable
WADDirectoriesTable
WADPerformanceCountersTable
WADWindowsEventLogsTable
```

Can someone explain if I need these tables and also why are there different tables on the emulator and on production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are storage analytics tables containing metrics data (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343258.aspx). They contain the data about how your storage is accessed and its performance. I'm not sure why they're there in your development storage account but for them to show up in your production storage account, you would need to explicitly enable storage analytics on your storage account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And the WAD* tables are from Windows Azure Diagnostics.